# How to use \pgfkeys properly in \newenvironment based on xcolor and tcolorbox?

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, pgfkeys, package-writing

I'm trying to create a **new environment** called `noteframe` that is based on `tcolorbox`.

Supposedly, the `noteframe` environment should allow the user to change the theme color of the box using the name of the color from `xcolor` package.

However, using the code below produces the undesirable result in the picture boxed in **red**.

The desirable result is boxed in **green**.

I am trying to use the following newly defined environment to achieve the `tcolorbox` result in **green** box in the picture below, whereas it produces the result in **red** box:

```
\begin{noteframe}[color = cyan] %%% if I don't write [color = cyan], the default color should be black
content
\end{noteframe}
```

Can anyone please help me modify the code to achieve the desired result?
**I have also attached the code for creating the environment below the picture**.

Thanks in advance!!!
[image: pic]

---

The way I create the environment is:

```
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} % color
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} % colored box
\usepackage{tikz}
\linespread{1.15}

\pgfkeys{
    /noteframe/.is family, /noteframe, 
    default/.style = {color = cyan},
    color/.store in = \boxcolor
}

\newenvironment{noteframe}[2]{
    \pgfkeys{/noteframe, default, #1}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        enhanced,
        boxrule=0pt,
        frame hidden,
        borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{\boxcolor!85!black},
        colback=\boxcolor!10!white,
        sharp corners
    ]
    #2
    \end{tcolorbox}
}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{noteframe}
    What happened here?
\end{noteframe}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax to define an environment is wrong. It takes two argument: the first with the begin code and the second with the end code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} % color
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} % colored box
\usepackage{tikz}
\linespread{1.15}

\pgfkeys{
    /noteframe/.is family, /noteframe, 
    default/.style = {color = cyan},
    color/.store in = \boxcolor
}

\newenvironment{noteframe}[1][]{
    \pgfkeys{/noteframe, default, #1}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        enhanced,
        boxrule=0pt,
        frame hidden,
        borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{\boxcolor!85!black},
        colback=\boxcolor!10!white,
        sharp corners
    ]}
{\end{tcolorbox}}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{noteframe}
    What happened here?
\end{noteframe}

\begin{noteframe}[color=red]
    What happened here?
\end{noteframe}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Hi Ulrike Fischer, would you be so kind to check out the question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/671012/287315

Thanks a lot :)