# Condition in Writing New Environment with pgfkeys

Tags: tcolorbox, pgfkeys, package-writing

I'm writing a new environment in LaTeX where `pgfkeys` package is used to give the key interface.

Source Code:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{noteframe}[2023/01/01 Version 1.0]

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\pgfkeys{
    /noteframe/.is family,
    /noteframe,
    default/.style = {
        color = cyan,
        frame = one
    },
    color/.store in = \boxcolor,
    frame/. store in = \boxframe
}

\newenvironment{noteframe}[1][]{
    \pgfkeys{/noteframe, default, #1}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        enhanced,
        boxrule = 0pt,
        frame hidden,
        \if\boxframe = one,
        borderline west = {3pt}{0pt}{\boxcolor!85!black},
        \fi,
        \if\boxframe = two,
        borderline west = {3pt}{0pt}{\boxcolor!85!black},
        borderline east = {3pt}{0pt}{\boxcolor!85!black},
        \fi,
        colback = \boxcolor!10!white,
        sharp corners
    ]}
{\end{tcolorbox}}
```

Intention: Use the command below to create colored box.

```
\begin{noteframe}[color=cyan, frame=one] %%% By default, color is cyan, and frame is one.
                                         %%% Color can be chosen from xcolor name, frame 
                                         %   has options of {one, two, zero}. 
    What happened here?
\end{noteframe}
```

When I run the command above with option `[color=cyan, frame=one]` LaTeX should produce a colored box with one side on the left of the box:
[image: one]

When I run the command above with option `[color=orange, frame=two]` LaTeX should produce a colored box with one side on the left of the box:
[image: two]

When I run the command above with option `[color=Lavender, frame=zero]` LaTeX should produce a colored box with one side on the left of the box:
[image: zero]

Could anyone please help me to check what is wrong with the **source code** above?
My code can only produce the two-line version of the tcolorbox (lines on the left & right of the box) even when I state `frame=zero` or `frame=one`.

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: I was trying to use `/.is choice` from `pgfkeys` to handle this, but still can't figured it out...